# Make vim remember the fileformat of a buffer

Tags: buffers, file-formats

I am using vim to view Spyder's Python comman history.  I set to `:e +=ff=dos` to get rid of `^M` at the end of each line.  When I switch to another file, then switch back, the `fileformat` is `unix` again.  Is there anyway to have vim remember the `fileformat` for the buffer?

Comment: try `:set hidden`

Comment: Thanks, Christian.  That works.  Care to post it as the answer?

Comment: Pity that this isn't a local setting...

Comment: `this isn't a local setting` Use `set bufhidden=hide` then.

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  Care to post this as *the* answer?

Answer (score 4):

Add `dos` to your `fileformats` option. If `fileformats` contains `dos` and all lines of a file end with `<CR><NL>` the `fileformat` option of that file is automatically set to `dos`.

**Addendum:** @ChristianBrabandt's comment to try `:set hidden` might be better if the file in question has mixed end-of-line styles. `set fileformats+=dos` only works if all lines end with `<CR><NL>`, while `:e ++ff=dos` prints a hint `[CR missing]`, but loads the file without showing the `^M`s anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Jurgen.  My `fileformats` already contains `dos`.  But `:set hidden` works fine.