# Make vim remember the fileformat of a buffer (round 2)

Tags: hidden-buffers, file-formats

I followed the advice [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20950/make-vim-remember-the-fileformat-of-a-buffer) to make only one buffer hidden so that it remembers settings like `fileformat=dos`:

```
set bufhidden=hide " This should be the solution
e ++ff=dos         " All the ^M symbols disappear (yay)
e                  " All the ^M symbols reappear  (boo)
setl ff            " Shows as unix                (boo)
set ff             " Shows as unix                (boo)
```

- The `set bufhidden=hide` is supposed to be the solution.
- The `e ++ff=dos` makes the `^M` symbols disappear from the ends of the lines (they were only present on some lines).
- The `e` brings the `^M` symbols back!
- The `setl ff` and `set ff` commands confirm that the `fileformat` reverted back to `unix` instead of staying `dos`.

**What am I doing wrong?**  Is there a solution that will persist?

I thought that my problem might be having set `nomodifiable` and `readonly`, but reversing both of these doesn't solve the problem.

I'm not sure if it matters, but the the buffer of interest is opening a Spyder command history file.  Spyder frequently updates the file and I want to use Vim to yank content into (say) `tmp.txt` for manipulation.

Comment: What do you have for `'fileformats'` (alias `'ffs'`)?

Comment: @B Layer: Both `set ffs` and `setl ffs` yield `unix,dos`.  Hmm, if I remove `unix`, the solution in my posted works.  Just reading up on it now.  I find the rules somewhat confusing.

Comment: The solution seems to be setting `fileformats` to nothing so that buffer-specific `fileformat` is not overridden: `:set ffs=`.  Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: Well, that disables auto-detection so it's certainly an option. A good place to start but maybe not the optimal solution. (E.g. `'bufhidden'` is a buffer-local setting....it looks like you set it then load another  buffer which, I think, overrides the setting. `:set hidden` OTOH is global.)

Comment: @B Layer: Thanks.  I avoided `:set hidden` because I don't want other buffers to be hidden.  Over the years, I ran across side-effects which I don't recall at the moment.  As for loading another buffer, maybe that's what I do.  I basically issue `:e` to update the contents of my Vim window because the Spyder command history file is frequently updated by Spyder.  I just want to yank contents from there for manipulation in another file `tmp.txt`.

Comment: Just regarding the first part....surprised you have issues/side-effects from `'hidden'`. Most Vim pros/veterans, to my knowledge, set this religiously. I do personally and never have any issues. In fact, it's indispensable and I don't know if I'd use Vim without it!

Comment: Hmm..OK, if I run into problems with `:set ffs=`, I'll set it back with `:set ffs=unix,dos` and try `:set hidden`.  Thanks.

Comment: `:edit` or `:edit %` intentionally reloads current file (`:h reload`) and so it also forces `ff` re-detection. Just don't do this.

Comment: @Matt: What is the best way to force an update, in lieu of `:edit`?

Comment: Why do you need to update? Was the file changed by another app?

Comment: @Matt: Yes, Spyder frequently updates the file.  I want to use Vim to yank content into `tmp.txt` for manipulation.

Comment: Then `set autoread` and no worries.

Comment: Or "frequently" means "really frequently"? Then you must do `:e +ff=dos`. Bind it to a mapping, for example.

Comment: @Matt: Sometimes, right away, as I am experimenting with code patterns both in Vim and the Spyder console.  If I had it my way, I would make Vim (via `readline`) and `fc` available at any command line (Matlab, Python, R).  `fc` (fix command) makes a world of difference in Unix shells.  Returning back to the posted question, so far setting `ffs=` nothing seems to be causing no grief.  Yet.

Comment: If you're not already doing so suggest you only unset `'ffs'` right before loading that particular file (filetype?) then restore it afterwards. Generally, you want to have autodetect on so if you can figure out how to disable it temporarily/situationally that's ideal. BTW, does it work if you (temporarily) `:set ffs=dos,unix` and don't pre-set `ff`? I'm wondering if autodetect will choose the opposite of what you're getting when you reverse order of the params as they are order dependent. (No big deal...just curious.)

Comment: Do you actually _need_ the file to be opened as `dos`? Does opening it as `unix` cause other problems, or is it literally just that you don't like seeing the `^M` characters?

Comment: CORRECTION: I deleted the buffer using `:bd`.  Then I issued `:set ffs=` and confirmed that the setting was empty.  I then opened the file in question with `:e /the/file/in/question.py` and saw the `^M` on many (not all) lines.  I issued `:e ++ff=dos` and the `^M` went away.  I then issued `:set ffs=unix,dos` followed by `:e` and the `^M` symbols came back.  Keeping `ffs=` nothing seems to be the best solution thus far.

Comment: @Rich: Yes, I push the cognitive and speed limits when mashing code patterns, so the `^M` is a significant liability.  You can say that I don't like seeing them, but their ultimate impact in terms of being able to get things done is nontrivial.  So much so that it's not worth the trial of copying and pasting such code to the Spyder console to see if it chokes.

Comment: Stepping back... Why isn't your file being recognized as a DOS-format file, if `ffs` *does* include `dos`? Do you have a mix of DOS and Unix line endings? Do you still have this problem if you save the file (which should consistently keep only DOS or only Unix line endings) and then load it again? Would converting the file to Unix line endings only not fix this?

Comment: @filbranden: The file has to be kept as readonly and nonmodifiable because it is Spyder's command history file. It has DOS and Unix line endings. I can infer the logic behind this. A code pattern almost always spans multiple physical lines, with situation-specific indentation. Not only can one complex statement sprawl over many lines, but I often copy/paste multiple statements into the Spyder console's command line. All the physical lines copied will show up in the log file without `^M`, except for the last one, which will have `^M`. That's just how Spyder managers its log file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an autocmd to have Vim execute `:e ++ff=dos` every time this particular file is read or reloaded.

Assuming the path to the file, after resolving symbolic links, is `~/VendorApp/DataCamp/Python/history.py` (according to your comment), then this autocmd should work for you:

```
autocmd BufRead ~/VendorApp/DataCamp/Python/history.py e ++ff=dos
```

So when you open the file, it will first be read using the normal automatic detection for line endings, but then this autocmd will trigger and reload it with `++ff=dos`. (Autocmd's by default are not nested, meaning the `:e` itself will not trigger the autocmd again.)

---

**NOTE:** Whenever you define an autocmd, make sure you add it inside an augroup, to prevent duplicate definitions if you end up reloading the script file where you defined it (such as your vimrc file.)

```
augroup spyder_history
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufRead ~/VendorApp/DataCamp/Python/history.py e ++ff=dos
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks!  Since I am using Cygwin's Vim with Anaconda's Spyder on Windows 10, I actually have the soft link to the history file located at an odd location.  The following adaption of your answer worked for me: `autocmd BufRead ~/VendorApp/DataCamp/Python/history.py e ++ff=dos`.  The actual location is `/c/Users/UserName/.spyder-py3/history.py`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on autocommand groups.  I always found autocommands confusing, but this `NOTE` prompted me to find the *right* location in the help.