# fileformat=dos not persistent despite "set hidden fileformats=dos,unix"

Tags: hidden-buffers, file-formats

I have posted about making `fileformat=dos` persistent in past years, [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20950/make-vim-remember-the-fileformat-of-a-buffer) and [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31265/make-vim-remember-the-fileformat-of-a-buffer-round-2).  So far, the best advice is `:set fileformats=dos,unix hidden`.  It does cause `fileformat=dos` to persist, but only for a little while

If I use Netrw to view a folder, then press `o` on a *file1* to split it open on a subwindow, I can issue `:e ++ff=dos` to get rid of the `^M` marks at the end of (almost) every line.  I can then close the subwindow, go to the next file *file2* and do the same thing.

If I close *file2* and press `p` on *file1* to open it in a preview window, it *seems* fine.  If I do the same for *file2*, however, then return to *file1*, I get the `^M` again.

This loss of `fileformat=dos` is sporadic.  That is, sometimes, it seems to OK, but at some point in switching between *file1* and *file2*, it comes back.  It seems to rear its head the most when I have two subwindows side-by-side, with Netrw on the left subwindow and the text file being inspected in the right subwindow (either in a preview window or a normal window).

Is there a more robust way to get `fileformat=dos` to stick to a buffer/file/subwindow?

Comment: I'm not sure if how persistent this solution is, but I `:set fileformats=` to nothing.  According to the help, when this global option is empty, Vim looks at the buffer-local option `fileformat`.  So with `bufhidden=hide`, the `dos` format seems to stick.  For now.